# Apply Möbius inversion to formal power series

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, mobius-inversion

Let $e$ be a positive natural number, there is the following equality of formal power series
$$\frac{1}{1-et}=\frac{\Pi_{i=1}^\infty(1+t^{2i-1})^{\alpha_{2i-1}}}{\Pi_{i=1}^\infty(1+t^{2i})^{\alpha_{2i}}}.$$

How can I use Möbius inversion to find the $\alpha$'s?

Comment: Take the logarithm of both sides, maybe multiply by $t$, and rearrange stuff a little. Are you sure the denominator isn't supposed to be $(1 - t^{2i})^{\alpha_{2i}}$?